# What is a term for something unwanted but which cannot be ignored?

Tags: word-choice

More specifically...

What is a term for a problem between sides that has surfaced that one would pretend to have always been submerged yet cannot be ignored?

For example, two sides always had potential and reason for conflict, but this was kept submerged, and purposefully ignored. Now, the conflict has surfaced and none can ignore it, though nobody wishes it were so. Institutional things especially. Imagine for example two government ministers who want to be on the same side but now realize that the conflict between them which they wish could have been ignored has emerged as something unavoidable, and that others can see it as well.

Comment: Can you give an example? Something tangible? Something psychological? etc..

Comment: *Anything* can be ignored, if you put enough effort into it.  (Until it kills you, of course.)

Comment: @HotLicks To an extent. But if, say, someone keeps kicking you in the shins, you can try to ignore them, you can pretend to ignore them, but you can't just not notice that they're doing it. Also, just because you CAN ignore something doesn't mean that you do. So I think it's fair to talk about things that a person is TRYING to ignore but which is difficult to ignore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something which is obvious but which people deliberately avoid or try to ignore can be called **the elephant in the room**.

Comment: Right, that's not far from the idea, but it's so cliché. But there might not be better as a term. Of course if I knew I wouldn't ask...

Comment: @Mallory-Erik - There is no simple English word for this concept, but there are idioms.  Idioms can be cliché, but sometimes that is what is best to communicate your idea clearly and concisely.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the issue as a Task, Burden, or Necessity. Or could use multiple terms such as saying, "The Mayor saw it as a burden which kept returning to eat up his time, however, the worried citizen knew it was a necessity to maintain the safety and security of their peaceful city."

Answer (score 0):

[800-pound gorilla in the room:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/800-pound%20gorilla) is an idiomatic expression that may describe to what you are referring to:

> - one that is dominating or uncontrollable because of great size or power. (M-W)
> - 800-pound gorilla" is an American English expression for a person or organization so powerful that it can act without regard to the rights of others or the law. (Wikipedia)

(TFD)

Comment: How long do you usually **hunt** before you catch a memory?

Comment: Right, not a memory, but a new untenable social reality that can't be ignored, esp institutional, organizational arrangements.

Comment: For example, two sides always had potential and reason for conflict, but this was kept submerged, and purposefully ignored. Now, the conflict has surfaced and none can ignore it, though nobody wishes it were so.  Institutional things especially. Imagine for example two government ministers who want to be on the same side but now realize that the conflict between them which they wish could have been ignored has emerged, and that others can see it as well.

Comment: I think "elephant in the room" is the far more common expression in the US.  "800 pound gorilla" is the thing that gets its way, regardless, and is not typically considered to be ignored.  Eg, the National Rifle Association in the US is an 800 pound gorilla, while climate change is the elephant in the room.

Comment: @HotLicks - OP is just referring to something that *cannot be ignored*.

Comment: But the parties are attempting to ignore it anyway.

Comment: Well, you can attempt at anything. My understanding is that it is  just there and its presence is going to be determinant.

Answer (score 0):

*What's a term for a dispute that's come to an impasse?*

**precipice** [pres-uh-pis] noun -[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/precipice)

> **2.** a situation of great peril: "on the precipice of war".

---

*What is a term for something unwanted but which cannot be ignored?*

**pressure**;  pres·sure \ˈpre-shər\ noun -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pressure)

> **5.**  the stress or urgency of matters demanding attention

I have a '*nagging feeling*' that neither of these words is what you're looking for, but we'll just '*keep a lid on that*' for the moment. Although they may disagree on many things, both the ministers think their courses of action to be '*necessary evils*' but are now '*under pressure*' from their constituents because '*the cat's out of the bag*'.

Answer (score -1):

inescapable : unable to be avoided or denied.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To make this into an answer and show that it is right, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: This actually looks like a good suggestion. However, you will need to add context on *why* your answer fits the request. In addition, you should cite the source you used for the definition and proper formatting.